# How can I convert a module to a list or an array before plotting?

Tags: python, function, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have 2 files in PyCharm:

**parable.py:**

```
def function_parable(a):

    return [x**2 for x in a]
```

---

**main.py:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a = np.array(a)
n = a.shape
print(n)
print(type(a))
print(a)

import parable as b
print(b.function_parable(a))
print(type(b))


plt.plot(a,b)
plt.show()
```

---

Error: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (5,) and (1,)

How can I maintain this structure and solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Why are you trying to plot `b`, and not `b.function_parable(a)`?

Comment: Use `x = b.function_parable(a)` and then `plt.plot(a,x)`

Comment: Thanks, Ben and Tom!! I've been venturing myself into Python for 2 weeks

Comment: if `a` is an array, use `return list(a**2)` instead of `return [x**2 for x in a]` in your function

Answer (score 2):

try the following script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a = np.array(a)
n = a.shape
print(n)
print(type(a))
print(a)

import parable as f
b = f.function_parable(a)
print(b)
print(type(b))


plt.plot(a,b)
plt.show()
```

Happy coding my friend.

Comment: I'm just using Python since 2 weeks ago. Thanks, man!!!